# Django detailed url

Tags: python, django, view

I'm trying to make seperated url for every entry for my blog app. But every time i try to go for example: localhost:8000/blog/3 it sends me response for regular localhost:8000/blog

I  tried to google it, and... i have no idea what i'm doing wrong.

My standard url.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
...
import blog.views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('home/', jobs.views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    ]
```

urls.py (in "blog app" folder):

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url('<int:blog_id>/', views.detail, name="detail"),
    url('', views.allblogs, name="allblogs"),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Article


def allblogs(request):
    #Mega object from database
    blog = Article.objects
    return render(request, "blog/allblogs.html", {'blog':blog})


def detail(request, blog_id):
    blog = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=blog_id)
    return render(request, "blog/detail.html", {'blog':blog})
```

In models.py don't know why i choosed "Article" instead of "Blog", but i don't think that matters here...

Any ideas... ?

Comment: You're confusing url (regex) and path syntaxes.

Comment: Classic: you use `path` notation instead of `url` notation, `<int:blog_id>/` is not valid for `url`s, only for `path`s.

Comment: Which version of Django are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using the correct notation, depending on your Django version.

Django 1.11 and lower:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
...
url(r'^$', views.allblogs, name='allblogs')
```

Django 2.0:

```
from django.urls import path
....
path('', views.index, name='allblogs'),
```

Comment: thanks. It worked. Is there a way to pass this (I needed to import "path" from extra module)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. See my edited answer if you are not sure about how to import `path` and `url`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use this method:
Template:

```
<a href="{% url 'blog:detail_blog' blog.pk %}" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-xs" >
<i class="fa fa-eye"> Edit</i>
</a>
```

in this case i say to the template that acces to app blog and the url detail_blog and send the pk(id) for get or show details.

your url principal:

```
urlpatterns = [
.......
.......
url(r'blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog')),
]
```

you urls.py from your app blog:

```
from blog.views import DetailBlog
urlpatterns = [
....
....
url(r'^detail_blog/(?P<pk>\d+)', DetailBlog.as_view(), name='detail_blog')
]
```

your views.py :

```
class DetailBlog(DetailView):
    model = Blog
    template_name = 'detail_blog.html'
    slug_field = 'title'
```

For more reference I provide this link:

[Vistas Genericas Django](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Generic_views)